# How to find out which files are outside git repository

Tags: git

Suppose we have a directory with a git repository & files:

```
.git
/test/inside-1.txt
/test/outside-1.txt
outside.txt
inside.txt
```

"inside" files are within git repository, "outside" are not. I'd like to know, how to get the files, that are outside repository and inside.

I know, how to get "inside": I need to run `git ls-files`, it outputs:

```
test/inside-1.txt
inside.txt
```

How to get the "outside" files in the same format?

```
test/outside-1.txt
outside.txt
```

Comment: How does your example output tell you what's in git and what's outside git?

Comment: the only difference I see in your expected output is that the `.git` file is not listed. Can you explain in words what you're trying to accomplish? sorting `ls` output? excluding files from it based on `git ls-files` output? something else?

Comment: @muru No, I wanted to get 2 outputs: all the files in folder and those who are in git. Then differentiate them using a script. If you know, how to get the files outside git immediately, please, let me know.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am trying to get 2 lists of files: inside git repository and outside git. `ls` and `git ls-files` are outputting the data in different formats when they are located inside subdirs. So, I want to find out is it possible to get `ls` output in the same format as git does.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question in my view, you're in the middle of a solution rather than at the start. You want to write a script, that when it looks at a directory and its contents, including sub-directories, lists all the files and directories which are not included in the git repository which covers the same location, yes?  If so - reword your question to that by editing it.

Comment: @EightBitTony I reworded it. Please, reopen.

Comment: @user4035 I didn't vote to close, and even if I did, I can't re-open it.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Can you reopen the question: I reworded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try with `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`. This should list files which are not defined in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the files outside repository, I had to use `git ls-files -o`:

```
$ git ls-files -o
test/outside-1.txt
outside.txt
```

Comment: Can you please re-word your question so that it actually describes what you're trying to achieve, otherwise it's very likely to be closed.  If you reword it, it'll help other people find your question in future.